# Windows Phone Emulator is doing complete os boot?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i installed 7.1 beta 2 developer tools in my laptop .while running the solution it's showing "Windows Phone Emulator is doing complete os boot?" i tried so many times as uninstall and re install the developer tools but no use.

Please tell me clearly  i am facing that error so many days i am not able to get how to fix that error.

please tell me why that error is occuring and how to rectify that error.

Comment: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68634/418918.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before.
I fixed it by deleting the files in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE` folder and then running a repair on the dev tools installation. I imagine a reinstall would also fix it.